# Game Center: how to get user's score?

Tags: ios, xcode4, game-center, gamekit

I have made a game which is supported by game center, it logs on the user and submits his score correctly, but I now need the game getting the score from game center, to let the user retrieve his score if he had to restore his device or to continue a match in a different device.
Sorry if the question is not correctly posted, could someone help please?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user logs in with the same game center ID, his scores will be synced automatically when you present the GKLeaderBoardViewController. The only thing I don't understand from the question is "or to continue a match in a different device".

`GKLeaderBoard` has this method:

```
- (void)loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *scores, NSError *error))completionHandler
```

which returns you an array of the scores, from there on, it's up to you to experiment and pull the required score. A tip is to set the timeScope of the GKLeaderBoard to `GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime` if you're using the score as a counter.

Also, if you're just using the scores as a counter and nothing else, why not use iCloud to sync the progress between devices. It's more automatic, and doesn't require the player to have game center.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that it is a game which works as a counter, so I want the user to be able to submit his progress (which is his game center score) from his iPhone and continue its progress in his iPad by getting his actual high score from Game Center. It's a bit confusing, I hope you understood, thanks!

Comment: hey see the edit, and consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it if it solves your answer

Comment: yes I have been searching throw google to learn iCloud syncing but I did not get any result that I could understand, could yo tell me about it? or just tell me where to learn syncing the score with iCloud for beginners, Thanks for your time, I will give you the check mark for helping

Comment: Check out these 2 tutorials, in your case the storage is pretty simple, you just need to store an integer that tells you about the users progress, you can use key-value storing for that, the tutorials should be all that you need and more to achieve that, good luck!!
http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1
http://www.raywenderlich.com/6031/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2